# Simple calculation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a `distance` field in my database that stores the distance traveled on a specific  route.  I need to select all the distance fields, add them together, and then return the result from my stored procedure.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SumDistances
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(Distance)
    FROM MyTable
END
```

Comment: Exactly. Never thought it would be that easy. Thank you! :-)